# Moving between Stack Exchange sites; why is it so bad?

Tags: feature-request, navigation

I love Stack Overflow and my love spreads out on other sites that sprung up from the success of stackoverflow.com but one thing needs to be improved: changing sites and getting to know what's been happening on other sites while being on one is absolutely rubbish, especially when you take into account that some people work in high resolution 1600×1200 or higher and are forced to move between beloved sites using 100×100 drop-down menu.

Think about something better.

I just found out that there are some Greasemonkey scripts to go around this issue, but that would be embarrassing. Navigation should be built-in on the website.

Comment: What pop-up window are you talking about? I don't think I've ever seen any Stack Exchange popup, let alone a tiny 100x100 one. EDIT: Are you talking about the dynamic thing that comes down from the SE logo and contains the global inbox?

Comment: Erm, there is navigation in the footer for moving between those sites.

Comment: Adding to what @Moshe says, how about having several sites open in different tabs? Honestly, it's not exactly rocket science. I'm looking at 16 SE tabs right now as we speak, I can easily switch between them at any time, and my screen resolution is not even remotely in the 1600×1200 ballpark, let alone higher.

Comment: pop-up changed for drop-down to satisfy semiotic demands although telling whether or not it's a pop-up window it's an academic issue

Comment: @Moshe: as you said it's in the footer, that means it's underneath 100th question (often)

Comment: @matcheek - Use your scrollbar. Also, see my answer.

Comment: Why is greasemonkey embarrassing?

Comment: I perceive navigation as a crucial part of the website, so having said that, calling for third-party solutions to sort this issue will always be embarrassing, not mentioning that I only found out about them when my frustration level got really high. Why not offer something that people can use before they get frustrated??

Comment: @matcheek - ok, fair point.

Comment: This is just rant, voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the footer navigation on any of the SE sites, or you can have different tabs open at once. Also, bookmarks are your friend.

Comment: with pain, but I'm using footer navigation and tabs.Still waiting for someone to fix this issue though.